# Javascript Closest p tag text not selecting

Tags: javascript

I am trying to grab my p tag text when user click share button. My code Here

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" style="width:90%;height:300px;overflow-y: scroll;">
                <label>- Title</label>          
             <p class="copy">Demo text
                <br />Demo text
                <br />Demo text,
                <br />Demo text.
                </p>
            </div>
                <div class="ui-grid-a" >
                    <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:44%;"><a class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="p">12 Likes</a></div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:44%;float:right;"><a href="#single-kobita" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all share-it">Share</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-grid-a" >
                    <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:44%;"><a class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all">Prev</a></div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:44%;float:right;"><a href="#1400-shal" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all">Next</a></div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

JavaScript Code

```
 $("a.share-it").click(function(){          

        var text = $(this).closest( "p" ).text();


    });
```

But text variable always empty. Please anyone help for this.

Comment: Does the selector actually find the element you want? You might want to first confirm that it is matching the desired element.

Comment: I want Paste it for Facebook share.. But can't selecting the text.

Answer (score 8):

Read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). The `.closest` returns the closest **ancestor** element that matches the selector. So, in your case, the innermost `p` element that is a container to your `a` element.

But your `a` is not inside a `p` so nothing is found.

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector **by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree**.

---

In your example code (*but this is a guess to the general structure you have*) this would work

```
$("a.share-it").click(function(){          
    var text = $(this).closest(".ui-content").find('p').text();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the closest common ancestor(in this case .ui-content)
Then find the p tag, then select the first one that was found, then request the text.

```
 $("a.share-it").click(function(){          
        var text = $(this).closest( ".ui-content" ).find('p').first().text();
    });
```

```js
 $("a.share-it").click(function(){             
            var text = $(this).closest( ".ui-content" ).find('p').first().text();
            window.alert(text);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" style="width:90%;height:300px;overflow-y: scroll;">
                <label>- Title</label>          
             <p class="copy">Demo text
                <br />Demo text
                <br />Demo text,
                <br />Demo text.
                </p>
            </div>
                <div class="ui-grid-a" >
                    <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:44%;"><a class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="p">12 Likes</a></div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:44%;float:right;"><a href="#single-kobita" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all share-it">Share</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-grid-a" >
                    <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:44%;"><a class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all">Prev</a></div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:44%;float:right;"><a href="#1400-shal" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all">Next</a></div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.